# How insert into table(User-defined type) from Stored procedure and passing to c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

How **insert into** table(User-defined type) from **Stored procedure** and passing to c#

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RegisterChoiceUserInitial](
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialJob] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialOrganization] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialUnit] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialMembershipType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialStart] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialEnd] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_RegisterChoiceUserInitial] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RegisterChoiceUserInitialID] ASC
)
```

**User-defined type:**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableTypeInitial] AS TABLE(
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [InitialJob] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [InitialOrganization] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [InitialUnit] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [InitialMembershipType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [InitialMembershipStart] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [InitialMembershipEnd] [nvarchar](10) NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make serialize/deserialize for your type, and write string of serialized object to SQL, then when you need to get it, you read string from table and deserialized it to your type.

**EDIT**

about serialize you can read here [csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file) They use serialize to file, but convert it to string will not be hard

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to return a datatable as output param. The only way to return table result from xp to c# is either using xml param or in following way.

**sql scripts :**

```
create procedure sp_returnTable
    body of procedure
    **select * from RegisterChoiceUserInitial**
end
```

**sample c# code:**

```
   string connString = "<your connection string>";
    string sql = "name of your sp";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

try {
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
   da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
   da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   DataSet ds = new DataSet();   
   da.Fill(ds, "result_name");

   DataTable dt = ds.Tables["result_name"];

   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
               //manipulate your data
   }

} catch(Exception e) {
   Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
} finally {
   conn.Close();
}
```